# CVS not updating TOAD

Tags: cvs, toad

I am a DBA so am not writing the code, just executing it. I have noticed an odd occurrence lately with CVS and TOAD. I update CVS using the modify and get no errors. I want to run a module of code that is now 1.5 but was 1.4 in CVS. I open TOAD and import the CVS script via the Windows File Explorer and it runs fine. If I open a second instance of a different database on the same TOAD session, to run the same code I get the CVS pre-update code. This has happened twice. I always check my CVS update works right. And the first instance is always right (1.5) update but the second is not I get the old (1.4). Anyone else noticed this? Something I need to do to make sure it works? This is a recent change. It has always given updates across the board previously. So I am puzzled as to what changed.

Comment: Please include in you question what have you tried, found or any relevant data. Question needs be a clear one

Comment: Don't know how to be clearer. It is simply not updating properly.